# same code is written as copied from webpage, but it is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I copied code from net for ajax, but when I write the exactly same code, it did not work. what can be the reason? because, I cannot find any error and even not changed the code but still it is not calling.

[image]

Comment: You need to add more context, how is it not working? Is it not firing? Is the call failing?   how is it triggered?

Comment: actually the function call() is triggered on "onkeyup" event. the non-commented code is running properly but the same code as i have comment is not running i-e the function inside onreadystatechange is not called in commented code

Comment: It would be helpful to have the code and not an image, I tested the commented code and it worked correctly, but as I said it was retyping it as you did.  For general reference code is always better than an image :)